# Access VBA: Attachment image won't load in form

Tags: vba, where-clause

I have a table that contains items, their location, and an attachment photo of the item.  The location is set up by row #-shelves #-shelf #.  For example 2-3-4 would be in the second row on the third set of shelves on the fourth shelf down.  I have another form that allows users to search by shelf.  Basically, they enter the first two numbers and I do this.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "fReview", , , "Location Like '" & locStr & "*'"
```

Where 'locStr' is the string containing 2-3 (the first two numbers), and when the form fReview opens, it should show all items on all shelves of the second row, third shelf unit.

This part works just fine.  However, when fReview opens, the image part of the attachment field that I put on the form stays blank.  The rest of the fields populate with no problems.  When I close the form and open it again normally (with no Where condition), the image works perfectly (although it does blink a few times like it is refreshing multiple times which is weird).  The form is linked to the table, so it should all be directly linked, so I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I created a brand new tiny database to test some things, and figured out my problem.  Thought I'd share it, just in case somebody eventually had the same problem I did.  It was actually pretty simple.

When I added the attachment field to my form, I just dragged it over from the "Add Existing Fields" bar.  This linked the Attachment.FileData as the control source for the field, which seemed ok.  Turns out that that isn't right for some reason.  If you change the control source to simply be the field name, it works.